# Ionic 2 get user's sim operator details

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm very new to ionic and cordova. I want to get user's phone number somehow, is it possible? I'm trying to create number registration for my app. When user opens an app the very first time it will send an confirmation message from phone & also the user only select the sim card to send a message.It's similar to PayZapp. The first view contains a button 'Select a sim', and the next view has a sim card options.

Comment: have you tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sim

Comment: No still i dont try that one.now i try this.Thank You